# Amazon CloudFront cross-origin headers on fonts

Tags: http-headers, cross-domain, amazon-cloudfront

I have a CloudFront distribution that blocks the font download in Chrome (desktop version) with the fallowing error:

> Font from origin 'https://....cloudfront.net' has been blocked from
>   loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://example.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

Where should I set this Access-Control-Allow-Origin header?

I tried adding the header in the "Origin" section of the could distribution but it does not produce any effect.

[image]

**EDIT #1:**

Nginx configuration on origin has the fallowing directive:

```
location ~ \.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$ {
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
}
```

which on this test `curl -I https://example.com/skin/frontend/smartwave/default/megamenu/css/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff`

Retuns the fallowing response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Tue, 02 Feb 2016 17:53:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/font-woff
Content-Length: 44432
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 May 2015 15:58:11 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "55537493-ad90"
Pragma: public
Cache-Control: max-age=31536000, public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

From what I see here this header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is missing.

Also I whitelisted the header on CloudFront so that it will not block it:

[image]

Comment: Definitely not in Origin Custom Headers.  What kind of server is the origin?  Specifically, is it S3, or a custom origin?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot this is a VPS in a data-center. Nothing related to Amazon

Comment: Hi @mugur, did you find how to configure it? I(ve the same problem with a rails app on heroku.

Comment: Hi @fro_oo, the problem was related to origin server and not to the amazon CloudFront. See answer please.

Answer (score 1):

That was hard to trace as the rules for headers were set in 2 different locations and not in one.

Fixing the correct header for the correct type of file did the job, but **you have to consider** the fact that in some locations **trying to overwrite the NGINX rules does not work**. *It will only consider the first rule.*

A comprehensive description of headers can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/1168944

Comment: So, what is the correct solution? Can not understand what to do exactly

Comment: @Emre add Access-Control-Allow-Origin header at origin (your server). A comprehensive description can be found here http://stackoverflow.com/a/10636765/1168944